# dotless MVC nuget package not working anymore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package, dotless

I have dotless 1.3.1.0 nuget package installed on VS2012 and since 2 days or so it doesn't work anymore. Not even in older Projects that I didn't edit.
Whole .less file stays colorless with no live sample on the right, no intellisense and it's not compiled into the .css file anymore.
Already tried to reinstall it but that didn't help.

Anyone else experiencing problems? Solution?

Comment: I have this problem with VS 2013. I assume the nuget package is no longer maintained. I went to the project site at http://www.dotlesscss.org/ and downloaded the latest package and added a reference to the dll from visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Since noone seems to answer (dotless is also pretty unknown) I can give a part solution myself. I installed Mindscape http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a that also has no highlighting in the left pane but it has a working right css pane. You can see that it doesn't work as it should do but it compiles and that's fine for now until I reinstall Visual Studio one day (I think VS is the problem).
Maybe that helps someone else too :-D